# Salesforce API - This session is not valid for use with the REST API - Invalid Session ID

Tags: python, salesforce, etl, simple-salesforce

For over a year, I have connected to Salesforce using the `simple_salesforce` package in order to pull some data from various objects and load it to a data lake.

I have used the authentication method using username / password / security token.

```
client = Salesforce(
    username="****************",
    password="*************",
    security_token="****************"
    )
```

On the 1st of February came the enforcement of [multi factor auth](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000356005&type=1). Starting on that day, I consistently hit the same error over and over.
`[{'message': 'This session is not valid for use with the REST API', 'errorCode': 'INVALID_SESSION_ID'}]`

After some research, I tried to add a permission set with API Enabled and then API Only user. Result: still the same error, but now I am locked out of the UI.

Has anyone else encountered similar issues and could point me towards the right resources, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MFA shouldn't matter for API access according to https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000352937&type=1 (Ctrl+F "API"), it's probably something else your admin did.

Username, password+token sounds like you're use SOAP login method.

See if you can create a "connected app" in SF to use the OAuth2 login method, more natural for REST API. I wrote a bit about it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62694002/313628. In the connected app you should be able to allow API access, even full if needed. No idea if Simple has natural place for the keys though, it's bit rubbish if you'll have to craft raw http requests yourself.

Simple's documentation also mentions using JWT to log in (and that requires connected app anyway), basically instead of username + pass you go username + certificate + the fact admin preauthorised this user... You'll be fine until certificate expires.

The text part of https://gist.github.com/booleangate/30d345ecf0617db0ea19c54c7a44d06f can help you with the connected app creation; sample code's probably not needed if you're going with Simple